# Generate animated GIF with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Are they any library to do so?

AFAIK dataToURL('image/gif') isn't supported by any browser

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Canvas can't generate (animated) GIFs. You need to use a JavaScript library to do so.

There is jsgif, a JS library to generate animated GIFs:
http://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif

This blog post explains the usage:
http://antimatter15.com/wp/2010/07/javascript-to-animated-gif/

Comment: has anyone been able to get the webworkers feature working? can't figure it out.

Comment: I am also having issues with web workers.

Answer (score 9):

omggif is a JavaScript implementation of a GIF 89a encoder.

https://github.com/deanm/omggif

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/ looks like an easier and better alternative to capture to gif or video.