# Save html code result as .gif or other video

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, spinning

So this may sound a bit odd already, but here it is:
I have some HTML code. In the HTML I use CSS to spin an image. So I want to somehow save this rotating image as a .gif or other video. Is this possible?

CODE:

```html
    <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      
      @-moz-keyframes spin {
        from {
       -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      
      #loading {

    height:300px;
    width:300px;
     border-radius: 150px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
     -moz-border-radius: 150px;
     box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);

        animation-name: spin;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 26s;
        animation-play-state: running;
        
        -webkit-animation-name: spin;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 26s;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        
        -moz-animation-name: spin;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-animation-duration: 26s;
        -moz-animation-play-state: running;
      }
    </style>
    <center>
    <img src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fire_fist_vs_water_fist-t2.jpg" id="loading">
    </center>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any other way except to get a screen recording software (Camtasia for example), record it, cut it, and turn it info a gif using an online converter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of this answers will help you. (or maybe not haha)

[Generate animated GIF with HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486084/generate-animated-gif-with-html5-canvas)